# Chern class of tangent bundle depend on almost complex structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold (not necessary compact) and $J$ be almost complex structure which is compatible with $\omega$,  then $(TM, J)$ can be regarded as a complex vector bundle over $M$. We can define the first Chern class $c_1(M, J)$ of  $(TM, J)$.

> My question: Does $c_1(M, J)$ depend on $J$?

Comment: The space of compatible almost complex structure is contractible, so the class would not change with respect to $J$.

Comment: Would you explain more detail why the chern class is invariant under isotopic of  almost complex structure?

Comment: @trick1234 Any two vector bundles in a continuous 1-parameter family of topological (not holomorphic) complex vector bundles are isomorphic as complex vector bundles (here a continuous family means a bundle over $M\times [0,1]$ which restricts to a vector bundle at each $t \in [0,1]$). There is an obvious homotopy of they classifying maps from $M$ to the infinite complex Grassmannian ($BU(n)$ if you like). And as the maps are homotopic they induced the same maps on cohomology (thinking of $c_1$ defined as a pulled back class from the classifying map)

Comment: I see, thank you very much~

Comment: If you swtich $J$ to $-J$, what effect does this have on the associated Chern classes?  (I am not necessarily trying to lead you to an answer with this question - I honestly don't know.)

Comment: If $J$ is $\omega$-tame, then $-J$ can't be $\omega$-tame as $\omega(v,Jv)>0\implies \omega(v,-Jv)<0$. If you are asking for the general case, then switching from $J$ to $-J$ replaces a complex vector bundle $E$ by its conjugated bundle $\bar{E}$ and we have $c_i(\bar{E})=(-1)^ic_i(E)$.